# How to convert a list<string> or list<object> to a ListView.ListViewItemCollection in one line

Tags: c#, linq

How can we transform a list of string or a list of object to a ListViewItemCollection in **one line** with linq, where object is for example a person with Name property that will be displayed to the ListViewItem.

Here is my current code :

```
foreach (string word in sf.lstWords)
{
  lvWords.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(word));
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`ListView.ListViewItemCollection.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1c1wawcw.aspx) and the Linq method [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)

```
lvWords.Items.AddRange(sf.lstWords.Select(t => new ListViewItem(t)).ToArray());
```

I use `ToArray()` because the signature of AddRange is void `AddRange(ListViewItem[])`