# Converting List<object> to ListView items (with subItems)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a pre-configured ListView (with column headers already set up), that I would like to task a list of object, and write - as rows to that listview - specific attributes of the class I have a list of.

I'm trying to follow [this existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676374/how-to-convert-a-liststring-or-listobject-to-a-listview-listviewitemcollecti/14676397#14676397), while it perfectly handles an item with only one column, I'm not sure how to apply multiple sub items.

I have a class that contains a `List<Product>` which is being handed off to a UserControl that takes that list and adds each product item to a ListView within the control.

While the linked Q&A handles this it's not complete, and I have no idea how to get other attributes into the ListView as SubItems.

My snippet: `Products.Items.AddRange(basket.ProductList.Select(p => new ListViewItem(p.Description)).ToArray());` where `p` is a `List<Product>`

I'd like also to have the item quantity, unit price and line total (which is worked out in the class already) in the listview, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Is this WPF or Forms ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - It is WinForms

Comment: Also, you should elaborate a little more, what exactly is the problem ? creating new columns for the view ? finding a product from a listviewitem ? etc ... or are you expecting a master-detail view ?

Comment: The listview is not well suited for this.  You'd have to add SubItems for each item.  On the other hand, if it was a datagridview, `myDGV.DataSource = basket;` is all you need

Comment: I've updated - but in short, I have a list of a class "Product" that I would like to convert into ListViewItems with SubItems, where the sub items are attributes of the class, eg. Quantity, Unit Price, Line Total etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListViewItem` class has a lot of constructors. The most appropriate for your case is [ListViewItem Constructor (String[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/faw83h4f(v=vs.110).aspx)

> public ListViewItem(string[] items)
>
> Initializes a new instance of the ListViewItem class with an array of strings representing subitems.

With your snippet, something like this

```
Products.Items.AddRange(basket.ProductList.Select(p => new ListViewItem(new string[]
{ 
    p.Description,
    p.Quantity.ToString(...),
    p.UnitPrice.ToString(...),
     ...  
})).ToArray());
```

Note that `ListViewItem.Text` is actually `ListView.SubItems[0].Text`.